# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference new activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity

When I'm trying start new activity with this code im getting tihs error:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

---

```
class ApiConnection {

    var baseApiURl = "http://localhost:8081"
    var data = arrayListOf<User>()

    fun connectApi(): ApiService {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseApiURl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }

    fun loginRequest(
        login: String,
        password: String
    ){
        val service = connectApi()
        val call = service.login(login, password)
        call.enqueue(object: Callback<UserResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.v("retrofit", "call failed")
            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserResponse>?, response: Response<UserResponse>?) {
                addDataToList(response)
            }

        })
    }

    fun addDataToList(response: Response<UserResponse>?) {
        var mainActivity = MainActivity()
        data.add(
            User(
                response!!.body()!!.idUser,
                response!!.body()!!.login,
                response!!.body()!!.password,
                response!!.body()!!.name,
                response!!.body()!!.surname,
                response!!.body()!!.lastLogin
            )
        )

        mainActivity.loginIntoServer(data)
    }
}
```

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val api = ApiConnection()

        button_checkIfThisAccountExit_mainActivity.setOnClickListener {
            api.loginRequest(editText_login_activityMain.text.toString(), editText_password_mainActivity.text.toString())
        }
    }


    fun loginIntoServer(data: ArrayList<User>) {
        val context = this
        val intent = Intent(context, Main2Activity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Any ideas what can make this error? I'm using retrofit to connect with my API and after parsing the result data and adding it to the list i would like to run new activity (something like a login system. After putting username/password I want change the activity).

Answer (score 1):

Source of your problem is `var mainActivity = MainActivity()`, You never create instance of activity by invoking the `constructor` because that is the job of `android` system, see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Correct solution to your problem would be [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).
but if you want to make your current code work as it is, you will have to pass a `context` `object` in your ApiConnection `class`,

```
fun addDataToList(context: Context, response: Response<UserResponse>?) {
        data.add(
            User(
                response!!.body()!!.idUser,
                response!!.body()!!.login,
                response!!.body()!!.password,
                response!!.body()!!.name,
                response!!.body()!!.surname,
                response!!.body()!!.lastLogin
            )
        )

        val intent = Intent(context, Main2Activity::class.java)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Also update the signature of `loginRequest` to accept a `Context` object from your `activity`, so that it look as following

```
fun loginRequest(context: Context, login: String, password: String)
```

And now call it from your activity as

```
api.loginRequest((this as Context), editText_login_activityMain.text.toString(), editText_password_mainActivity.text.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

How in your opinion this code should look? 
Only corrently working code isnt enought for me if you know what I mean.
I also want to have the code which is looking good.